# What do the red-background numbers on user pages represent?

Tags: support

[image: numbers on favorites at 16:59] [image: numbers on favorites at 17:07]

In the pictures above, taken from the *Favorites*<sup>†</sup> subpage of some random userpage first at 23:59Z and then at 00:07Z, what do the various numbers highlighted with red background represent?  Is there a place on stackexchange that explains such things?

Note, the tooltips associated with words next to the numbers summarize what the words mean but don't spell out what the numbers mean and when or why they change.

<sup>†</sup> *Favorites* meaning *To look at*, not *Liked*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number refers to notifications about the items in each tab.

So, you gained 965 reputation since checking it last, have 496 responses (answers, comments, etc.), and 82 of your favourite questions have had activity on them (edits, new answers, etc.).

The counts are cleared when you visit the tabs. When you do, new items aren't really highlighted in any way, although you can sort the Favourites tab by "activity" and see which questions changed recently.

Comment: Anna, although I upvoted your answer when it appeared, I didn't accept it because it doesn't answer “Is there a place on stackexchange that explains such things?”.

Comment: @jwpat7 There isn't really a place, no. Many things are documented on [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com), but in most cases it's easier to just ask on your site meta, like you did.

Comment: Thanks.  Also, I see I had accepted the answer, but due to the checkmark's low color saturation thought I hadn't.